# Showing refresh button when animation is complete?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I would like to know how to write the jQuery to show a hidden button when an animation is complete. The Button must refresh that animation so the user can watch the animation again.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/ZeMcP/

HTML

```
<div class="bar1"><div class="alt0"></div></div>

<div id="button"><a href="#">refresh</a></div>
```

CSS

```
.bar1 {
width: 200px;
height: 20px;
background-color: black;
}
.alt0 {
width: 0px;
height: 20px;
background-color: orange;
}
#button {
display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.bar1').mouseenter(function(){
 $('.alt0').animate({width: "200px"}, 1000)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the complete callback provided by [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
$('.bar1').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.alt0').animate({
        width: "200px"
    }, 1000, function(){
        $('#button').show();
    })
});
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('.alt0').width(0);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yXy6u/)

Answer (score 3):

You can add complete function

```
$('.bar1').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.alt0').animate({
        width: "200px",
        complete: function () {
            $("#button").toggle();
        }
    }, 1000)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [callback](http://w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp): `$(selector).animate({params},speed,callback);`

like this:

```
$('.bar1').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.alt0').animate({width: "200px"}, 1000,function(){
        $("#button").css("display","block");
        })
});
$("#button").click(function(){
                   $("#button").css("display","none");
$(".alt0").css("width","0px");
                   });
```

[**jsFiddle is here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZeMcP/3/)